# CoinChange Problem with DP in Java using 2D array

Tags: java, 2d, dynamic-programming

I am implementing an algorithm to solve the [Coin Change](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/) problem, where given an array that indicates types of coins (i.e. `int[] coinValues = {1,4,6};`) and a value to achieve (i.e. `int totalAmount=8;`), an array is returned where the value at position 0 indicates the minimum number of coins needed to achieve `totalAmount`. The rest of the array will keep a track of how many coins are needed to achieve the total sum.

An example input of `coins = {1,4,6}` and `total = 8` should return the array `[3,2,0,1]`. However, my code is returning `[1,2,0,1]`.

Another example would be `coins = {2,4,8,16,34,40,64}` and `total = 50` should return the array `[2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`. My code is not returning that result.

The algorithm is implemented with 2 methods: `CoinChange` and `CoinCount`. `CoinChange` creates the coin matrix and `CoinCount` keeps track of the coins required to achieve the total sum.

```
package P5;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CoinChange7 {

    public static int[] CoinChange(int[] v, int sum) {

        int[][] aux = new int[v.length + 1][sum + 1];

        // Initialising first column with 0
        for(int i = 1; i <= v.length; i++) {
            aux[i][0] = 0;
        }
        // Implementing the recursive solution
        for(int i = 1; i <= v.length-1; i++) {

            for(int j = 1; j <= sum; j++) {
                if(i == 1) {

                    if(v[1] > j) {
                        aux[i][0]=999999999; //instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE

                    } else {

                        aux[i][j]=1 + aux[1][j-v[1]];

                    }
                } else {

                    if(v[i] > j) { //choose best option ,discard this coin or use it.

                        aux[i][j] = aux[i - 1][j];


                    } else

                        aux[i][j] = Math.min(aux[i-1][j],1 + aux[i][j-v[i]]);
                }
            }
        }
        int []z=CoinCount(sum,aux,v);
        return z; // Return solution to the initial problem
    }

    public static int[] CoinCount(int A, int[][] aux, int[] d){
        int coin = d.length-1;
        int limit=A;

        int [] typo=new int[d.length+1]; //We create solution array, that will count no of coins

        for (int k=0;k<typo.length;k++) {

            typo[k]=0;

        } while (coin>0 || limit>0){

            if(limit-d[coin]>=0 && coin-1>=0){

                if(1+aux[coin][limit-d[coin]]<aux[coin-1][limit]){

                    typo[coin+1]=typo[coin+1]+1;

                    limit=limit-d[coin];
                } else {

                    coin=coin-1;
                }
            } else if(limit-d[coin]>=0) {

                typo[coin+1]=typo[coin+1]+1;

                limit=limit-d[coin];
            } else if(coin-1>=0) {

                coin=coin-1;

            }
        }

        typo[0]= aux[d.length-1][A];
        return typo; //return the final array with solutions of each coin
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] coins = {1,4,6};
        int sum = 8;
        int[] x=CoinChange(coins,sum);


        System.out.println("At least " + Arrays.toString(x) +" from set "+ Arrays.toString(coins)
                + " coins are required to make a value of " + sum);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Javo, welcome to StackOverflow! `it doesn't work properly` is rarely a good summation of a problem, can you clarify? What *exactly* is not working - is a variable not being updated, is there an error being thrown?

Comment: Hi Brydenr, with "it doest work properly", i mean literally that, above the code, i posted two exaples of what the algorithm returned. One case worked nice, but the other case didnt had the same luck. Did i explained well?
I mean, CoinChange works good cause was the first algorithm i created and it returned the correct amount of total sum. The problem comes when i call CoinCounter, which, i think works properly, and then the final result doesnt look good. I hope ive explained well...

Answer (score 1):

### Clarification

I don't know if you still need the answer to this question but I will try to answer it anyway.

First, there are a few things I would like to clarify. The coin change problem does not have a unique solution. If you want both the minimum of coins used to make the change and frequencies of coins usage, I think that depends on the approach used to solve the program and the arrangement of the coins.

For example: Take the coins to be `[4,6,8]` and `amount = 12`. You'll quickly see that the minimum coins required to make this change is `2`. Going by your choice of output, the following are all correct: `[2,0,2,0]` and `[2,1,0,1]`.

By the way, the Coin change problem can be solved in many ways. A simple recursive DP approach in Java [is here](https://github.com/Wilson-Emmanuel/algorithms/blob/master/src/leetCode/CoinChangeByRecursiveDP.java). It only returns the min coins needed to make the change at `O(nlog(n))` time and `O(n)` space.

Another approach is by using a 2D DP matrix (same with the approach you tried using) at both `O(n^2)` time and space. Explanation on how to use this approach [is here](https://riptutorial.com/dynamic-programming/example/25891/minimum-number-of-coins-to-get-total). Please be careful with the explanation because it is not generally correct. I noticed it's almost the same as the one you used.

### **Your solution**

I will mention a few things about your solution that may have affected the result.

1. The number of rows of the DP matrix is `v.length` not `v.length + 1`.
   Based on your solution, this should not affect the result because I noticed you don't seem comfortable with zero indexes.
2. I think it is not necessary to initialize the first column of the DB matrix since the data type you used is `int`, which is `0` by default. Again, this does not affect the answer, though.
3. The way you filled `row 1` (supposed to be the first row, but you ignored row 0) is not good and may affect the result of some solutions.
   The only mistake I see there is that there is no uniform value to specify amounts (i.e. `j`) that cannot be solved using the single coin (i.e. `v[0]`). Negative numbers could have been better because any positive integer is a potential valid solution for the cell. You could use `-1` (if you're going by the Leetcode instruction). This way, you'll easily know cells that contain invalid values while filling the rest of the matrix.

   The way you compute `aux[i][j]` is wrong because you are using the wrong coins. you are using `v[i]` instead of `v[i-1]` since you `aux.length` is one bigger than the `v.length`.
4. I did not look at the `countCoint` method. It looks complex for a seemingly simple problem. Please see my solution.

### **My Solution**

```
public int[] change(int[] coins, int amount){

    int[][] DP = new int[coins.length][amount+1];

     //fill the first column with 0
    //int array contains 0 by default, so this part is not necessary
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
        DP[i][0] =0;
    }
     */


    //fill the first row.
    //At 0th row, we are trying to find the min number of ways to change j amount using only
    //one coin i.e. coins[0] (that is the meaning of DP[0][j];
    for (int j = 1; j <= amount; j++) {
        if(coins[0] > j || j % coins[0] != 0){
            DP[0][j] = -1;
        }else{
            DP[0][j] = j /coins[0];
        }
    }

    //iterate the rest of the unfilled DP
    for (int i = 1; i < coins.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < amount+1; j++) {

            if(coins[i] > j){
                DP[i][j] = DP[i-1][j];
            }else {
                int prev = DP[i-1][j];
                int cur = 1+DP[i][j-coins[i]];

                if(cur == 0){
                    DP[i][j] = DP[i-1][j];
                } else if(prev == -1) {
                    DP[i][j] = 1 + DP[i][j - coins[i]];
                }else{
                    DP[i][j] = Math.min(DP[i-1][j],1+DP[i][j-coins[i]]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return countCoin(coins,amount,DP);
}
public int[] countCoin(int[] coins, int amount, int[][] DP){

    int[] result = new int[coins.length+1];//The 1 added is to hold result.
    int i = coins.length -1;
    int j = amount;
    //while the rest will contain counter for coins used.
    result[0] = DP[i][j];
    if(result[0] ==0 || result[0] ==-1)return result;

    while (j > 0 ){
        if(i-1 >= 0 && DP[i][j] == DP[i-1][j]){
            i = i-1;
        }else{
            j = j - coins[i];
            result[i+1] += 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```